# Cancelling Ajax request on closing of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some jquery which is designed to make an ajax request when the div is open. What I am concerned about is that there is potentially quite a bit of html to be loaded in the ajax call, and if the user if faffing about with the toggle button which opens and closes the div, the ajax request would still be continuing even after the user has closed the div.

My question is; Do I need to worry about stopping the ajax request when the div is closed, and if so how to I bind this onto the div being closed?

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/mz8Sm/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#country_slide').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#country_link').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        // Exit if the data is loaded already
        if ($link.data('loaded') === true) {
            console.log('Not using Ajax.');
            $("#country_slide").slideToggle();
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#country_slide .content").html('<p>Loading</p>')
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log('Fecthed with Ajax.');
                $("#country_slide .content").html(data);
                $("#country_slide").slideToggle();
                // If successful, bind 'loaded' in the data
                $link.data('loaded', true)
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
            },
            complete: function () {
            },
        });
    });
});
```

It looks like this is what I am after but I can't seem to bind it correctly onto the toggle only when it is being closed.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: you can abort a request, but the server side request will be still cotinueing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('#close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#country_slide').slideToggle();
        if(loadxhr){
            loadxhr.abort();
        }
    });

    var loadxhr;
    $('#country_link').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        // Exit if the data is loaded already
        if ($link.data('loaded') === true) {
            console.log('Not using Ajax.');
            $("#country_slide").slideToggle();
            return false;
        }

        loadxhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#country_slide .content").html('<p>Loading</p>')
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log('Fecthed with Ajax.');
                $("#country_slide .content").html(data);
                $("#country_slide").slideToggle();
                // If successful, bind 'loaded' in the data
                $link.data('loaded', true)
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
            },
            complete: function () {
                loadxhr = null;
            },
        });
    });
});
```